# Hide error page in Apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, python

I am running a python cgi-script on Apache server. Whenever I receive an error in the script, I get this error page:

[image: Error Page]

How can I hide/customize this error page for hiding the python code that gets highlighted on the page?

Comment: This might be better  on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution for it.
Just had to pass *display* argument in cgitb.enable() method.
`cgitb.enable(display=0)`